# How to response with HTML page SparkJava

Tags: java, html, spark-java

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769455/java-spark-framework-use-straight-html-template) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197544/how-to-return-a-static-html-page-with-spark-java) answer but none of them worked. The first one works only for `index.html`(you do not need to specify path and stuff like that). The code from the second solution gives me `NullPointerException` although the file exists and Spark returns `index.html`.

Helper class

```
class Helper(){
   String renderContent(String htmlFile) {
       try {
           return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(getClass().getResource(htmlFile).toURI())), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
       } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           mailSendingList.add(e.toString());
       }
       return null;
   }
}
```

Routes

```
get("/404", (req, res) -> helper.renderContent("404.html"));
```

Exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Helper.renderContent(Helper.java:177)
at Main.lambda$main$1(Main.java:33)
at spark.SparkBase$1.handle(SparkBase.java:311)
at spark.webserver.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:159)
at spark.webserver.JettyHandler.doHandle(JettyHandler.java:60)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:179)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:451)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.run(HttpChannel.java:252)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:266)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:240)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:596)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:527)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My file path was wrong. Changing `("404.html")` to `("public/404.html")` helped.

Answer (score 1):

check the return of `getClass().getResource(htmlFile)`, this probably is null because the resource is not found.

If you have the file "404.html" and the root of your classpath, change your code to (notice the insertion of '/')

```
get("/404", (req, res) -> helper.renderContent("/404.html"));
```

Comment: and what is the result of the `getResource(htmlFile)` call? Is this resource found?

Comment: it throws me a NullPointer, but I've solved the problem. See the coment below the question